# Alamofire using CocoaPods and xcode 6.3

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am kind of new to swift and xCode in general, I have installed Cocoapods and have a new xcode project.

I was able to add other libraries, but when i try to load the alamofire library, i get about 48 errors.

my Podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'TwilioSDK'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
```

When I try to build the app i get the following:

```
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:82:93: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:222:19: Static properties are only allowed within structs and enums; use 'class' to declare a class property
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:234:19: Static properties are only allowed within structs and enums; use 'class' to declare a class property
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:241:84: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:241:84: Expected ',' separator
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:241:84: Expected expression in list of expressions
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:263:59: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:268:10: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:821:61: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:937:43: Expected '{' after 'if' condition
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:939:13: Braced block of statements is an unused closure
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:942:14: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:942:15: Expected expression
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:942:20: Braced block of statements is an unused closure
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:968:59: Expected '{' after 'if' condition
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:972:70: Expected '{' after 'if' condition
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1141:65: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1176:65: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1176:65: Expected ',' separator
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1176:65: Expected expression in list of expressions
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1260:69: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1335:67: Expected type after 'as'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1335:67: Expected ',' separator
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1335:67: Expected expression in list of expressions
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1348:71: Expected '{' after 'if' condition
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1351:9: Braced block of statements is an unused closure
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1379:43: Expected '{' after 'if' condition
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1381:9: Braced block of statements is an unused closure
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:222:12: Static variables not yet supported
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:234:12: Static variables not yet supported
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:241:51: Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:253:33: Function produces expected type 'String'; did you mean to call it with '()'?
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:106:43: Use of unresolved identifier 'mutableURLRequest'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:122:17: Use of unresolved identifier 'mutableURLRequest'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:123:17: Use of unresolved identifier 'mutableURLRequest'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:127:17: Use of unresolved identifier 'mutableURLRequest'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:128:17: Use of unresolved identifier 'mutableURLRequest'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:131:28: Use of unresolved identifier 'mutableURLRequest'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:134:17: Use of unresolved identifier 'mutableURLRequest'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:190:19: Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'NSURL'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:939:13: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:942:20: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:970:13: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1312:38: Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'NSURL'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1333:65: Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'NSURL'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1351:9: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1382:39: Use of unresolved identifier 'escapedBody'
/****/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift:1385:35: Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'NSURL'
```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/433). Everything is working properly for the general public. I would certainly try @mattt's suggestion of `pod update` and other common CocoaPods troubleshooting tactics.

Comment: Also tried `pod update` this isn't solving the issue.

Comment: Ok turns out my Xcode wasn't on 6.3. Check your version and go `pod update`.

Comment: @mattt I got this problem too with 1.2, I downgraded to 1.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however this was fixed by downgrading to a lower version of Alamofire (1.1.4) and installing manually instead of using cocoapods.

Comment: The latest version of Alamofire works in XCode 6.3 if you build for your iOS device rather than build for a simulator. You can use this method until a new version of Alamofire is released.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the misleading questions, I've thought I've updated xcode but I didn't. for using xCode 6.2, selecting version 1.0.0 did the trick.

Thanks for answers